# How to upload projects from github onto my current text editor which is sublime

Tags: ruby, bundler

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

$ gem -v
2.5.2

$ bundle -v
Bundler version 2.0.2

So I'm not sure how to get my work on github from my command line. Is there something specific that I have to type from my text editor?

I keep getting a bundler message saying this

Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.0.2)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

and then this:

Successfully installed bundler-2.0.2
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.0.2
Done installing documentation for bundler after 8 seconds
1 gem installed

ok good now bundle install

Back to the original error message
please help I just want to get started lol

Comment: you need to go through a tutorial for `GIT` - Have a look at this [LINK](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-version_control)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you have git installed and use the clone command, to clone the repository using the git command in your command-line / console application or using GitHub desktop. Then you open your project using sublime or any editor of your choice.

```
git clone <repo URL here>
cd <project>
subl .
```

Comment: Ok so the git clone worked and I was able to get into the directory. Then I do sub1 and I get this.

Comment: I try bundle install I get the original error message about the outdated bundler

Comment: This is what I have in my gem file.exe

Comment: source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'rack', '~> 2.0.1'
gem 'rspec'


gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.0'
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

Comment: the command is subl (with an l), you may need to add it to your system path. The bundler message may just be a friendly reminder that there is a new version. If it is bombing about an SSL issue, you need to update RubyGems with the command `gem update --system`